# Cloudfunction/Serverless OAuth2 Client

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I'm new to OAuth2 and cloud-functions/serverless.

So I was wondering whether it makes sense to create cloud-functions to handle OAuth2 requests.

My Idea:

1. User sends auth request to and API Gateway (to prevent cloud-function abuse, as of my understanding, or how else should that be prevented? Cloudflare?)
2. Gateway redirects request to cloud-function
3. Cloud-function stores user authentication in DB
4. User is now authenticated.
5. The authenticated user can now request actual data, like profile, through other cloud-functions.
6. Response with data to the user.

Is this a correct understanding of how OAuth works? If so, does this make sense, or would a usual server be cheaper to handle OAuth?

Comment: You should consult the pricing guides for the options you're considering, estimate your usage, them use the guides to come up with a cost comparison.

Comment: I'm actually mostly wondering whether the way I describe it is correct and if it would work that way. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you described should work. Note that you will need to [secure your Cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) and besides the OAuth, do not forget to configure your function-to-function authorisation layer (as I understood that you will use more Cloud Functions). I think this process can be a pain, as you will need to configure it for each function. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function) you can find more details about it.

Although, what you have described should work, me, personally I would not implement that and I would go for an [Ambassador architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/ambassador) with a service running on 
[Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) ,let's say, that include the security layer, also. I would not choose your architecture plan for a few reasons:

1) I think it will be more complicated to configure mainly because what I was talking before.

2) Even though it is possible and people do this, I would not use Cloud Functions for querying databases in general, because this is a process which may take some time and your Cloud Function may timeout under some specific circumstances. ( maybe if there are a lot of ongoing connections to your db in that moment, it could cause high latency ).

3) Maintenance and debugging may be a little more difficult in a ¨chain¨ system like this.

4) I think that in case of really high traffic the cloud functions based architecture may be more expensive. You can check this out using the [Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/).

In conculsion, I think it will work, but I would not do it like this.